# Why can't I receive the quest after "Revealing the Unseen"?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I went to Savos Aren at the college after finishing the "Revealing the Unseen" quest, then we open the gates in the College of Winterhold because they were locked. Savos goes to the elf guy doing magic and poof! I awoke in front of this lady and she tells me to find the Arch Mage. At that point, the quest would not come up, and everyone just goes back to normal.

What's going on?

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't talked to Tolfdir go and talk to him. That is how you start the next quest.

Comment: Iv watched it on youtube u go outside and then u get a quest to defend the collage or somthing like that..

Comment: Yes you go up to Tisdel and he asks what happened. You tell him then he says that you need to defend the city.

Comment: Where do i find him?

Comment: He normally hangs out in the hall of attainment on the ground floor.

Comment: Cant find him..

Comment: Probably because his name is Tolfdir.