# Is there anyway to fix a bugged quest?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Help, the next quest would not come up after iv don the reavealing the unseen please help](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/47251/help-the-next-quest-would-not-come-up-after-iv-don-the-reavealing-the-unseen-pl)

The quest I am to do is to find the archmage but he is dead and the other people at the college will just go on as normal.

Comment: You already asked a question about this quest...

Comment: Nobody helped me on that one..

Comment: You may not receive an answer right away.  There is one answer to the question.  If that answer does not help, try adding more information.  Creating duplicate questions will not help you get an answer faster.

Comment: Well sorry, are you ok?

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing the [containment](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Containment) quest by any chance?  The archmage is supposed to be dead at that point.  What you have to do is continue into winterhold (the town), and find the anomalies that you need to defeat.

Comment: Yes, i did go to the town but found nothing:(

Comment: @dudegjersvik if you are on the PC, open up the console and type in: setstage MG05 50

Comment: And the quest containment would not come up as a quest..

Comment: I typed setstage MG05 50. Then it comes item "mag05" not found for parameter quest

Comment: its MG05, not MAG05

Comment: Miss cliked, ment MG05