# There is a bug where you will not receive the quest after the Eye of Magnus has been overloaded what to do?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

There is a possible bug where you will not receive the quest after the Eye of Magnus has been overloaded, what to do ?

Comment: You overloaded the Eye and killed Ancano?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Help, the next quest would not come up after I've done Revealing the Unseen](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/47251/help-the-next-quest-would-not-come-up-after-ive-done-revealing-the-unseen)

Comment: dude you've already asked this question multiple times.

Comment: @yx. they are not the same quest

Comment: @origamirobot they are, the original question was just titled with the wrong quest, but if you read the actual content, it is referring to this one (where arcano has taken control of the eye of magnus).  He refers to this as 'overloading it'

Answer (score 1):

If you are on PC, you can try to use

```
resetquest MG08
```

to reset the quest and do it again if you did not kill Ancano and the quest is somehow stuck. If Ancano is dead, there is also a way to ressurect him and defeat him again.

http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Eye_of_Magnus

Backing up / creating an extra savegame is actually suggested.

http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console

Answer (score 1):

try finding and giving tolfdir his alembic before entering the hall with the archmage, I had this problem for months and noticed that every time i talked to tolfdir he was missing his alembic . I think it causes him to stay in his room   and never notice the arch mage body. i play on ps3 and as soon as i did it the mission went normally and the next mission started and outside tolfdir and the others were standing by arch mage, and we fought the 10 magic anomalies and everything was normal .